# Stanford NER - Caught OutOfMemory, changing m

Tags: stanford-nlp

While training a model using Stanford NER 2016-10-31 the following line was output:

```
Iter 7 evals 17 <D> [M 1,000E0] {Caught OutOfMemory, changing m from 25 to 5}] |2,519E4| {1,000E-1} 2,295E-2 -
```

What does this mean (what is m?) and how does it affect the training of the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got similar warning. Here is minimal explanation:

References:

1. [An implementation of L-BFGS for Quasi Newton unconstrained minimization in Stanfordnlp CoreNLP](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/QNMinimizer.java)
2. Numerical Optimization (second edition) 2006,  Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright

As per (1), m is

```
* mem - the number of previous estimate vector pairs to
* store, generally 15 is plenty.
```

As mentioned in the book (2) - " the algorithm tends to be less robust when m is small."

So, number of recent correction pairs is decreased on OutOfMemory, however, you still have a good chance to solve the optimisation problem with  limited-memory BFGS algorithm